# How to use a form to change the file of a Django ImageField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField('member profile pic', upload_to = 'member_pictures')
```

I have got the following settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In my project **urls.py**, I have the media server set up as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # My application url
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp'))

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my app **urls.py**, I have the following url for the view:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^member/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/picture$',
        views.member_edit_picture,
        name='member_edit_picture',
    ),
]
```

Now, I am using a simple form to handle the image upload system. My **forms.py** looks like this:

```
class MemberPictureForm(forms.Form):
    picture = forms.ImageField(
        label='Select a profile picture'
    )
```

And finally, I am handling the form using my view in the following way:

```
@login_required
def member_edit_picture(request, pk):
    member = Member.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if not request.user == member.user:
        return HttpResponse("You do not have the permission to do that.")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        member_form = MemberPictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if member_form.is_valid():
            member.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            member.save()
            return redirect('myapp:member_edit_picture', pk=pk)
    else:
        member_form = MemberPictureForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/member_edit_picture.html', {
        'member' : member,
        'member_form' : member_form,
    })
```

In my template, I am handling the form in a normal way as well

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{member_form|crispy}}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I select an image, the file name shows up beside the choose button. When I click submit however, the view reloads, but the choose button field turns red and it says no file was chosen. Why isn't my form working? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the file upload docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.